# Selenium with Chromedriver can't allow Chrome to know Location

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geolocation

I can't allow Chrome to know Location when appears the popup asking if i want to allow.

I use the nuget Selenium 4.3.0 with .Net 6 and chromedriver version 103.0.5060.66

I tried a lot of solutions that i found on internet (Stackoverflow, medium, github Issue list, etc..) but nothing work and i don't know if i'm doing somenthing wrong or there are some bug in the new version of selenium (i tried to downgraded to 4.0.0 and still the problem)

I Use the following ChromeOptions:

```
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
  chromiumOptions.AddArguments("headless");
  chromiumOptions.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  chromiumOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
  chromiumOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
  chromiumOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
```

I tried the following options whithout results: (Also try with AddAdditionalCapability and AddAdditionalOption)

```
chromiumOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 1);
chromiumOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation", 1);
```

Also i tried with cdp command

```
Dictionary<string, object> commandParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
commandParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
commandParameters.Add("origin", "https://www.openstreetmap.org");
commandParameters.Add("permissions", new List<string>() { "geolocation" });
seleniumBrowser.ExecuteCdpCommand("Browser.grantPermissions", commandParameters);
```

But nothing works and still appear the Chrome Location Popup asking if i want to allow.

Thanks in advance!